# How to stop a C file reading before EOF?

Tags: c, file

I have a file which is a series of numbers that I am reading through C and then storing in an array. There is a new line at the end of the list which the pointer reads and sends to my array, which is problematic.

List of numbers:

```
9
8
6
5
23
42
```

Code:

```
FILE* fichier=NULL;
fichier = fopen("resultat.txt","r");
int i=0;
int ID[50];
while(fgetc(fichier)!=EOF && i<50){
    fscanf(fichier,"%d",&ID[i]);
    printf("%d\n",ID[i]);
    i++;
}
fclose(fichier);
```

Output I *have*:

```
42
23
9
8
5
6
5
17081006
```

Output I *want*:

```
42
23
9
8
5
6
5
```

How can I stop it reading the last (empty except for a return) line?

Comment: Break out of the loop after encountering two consecutive `'\n'`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lays on the behaviour of `feof()` and the way you are using it. `feof()` works by returning **whether the last read operation on a file read the EOF mark or actual data** *(well, you are using `fgetc()` but the behaviour is the same anyway)*

Your read loop doesn't do a read before asking for `EOF`. Instead, you are first asking if `EOF` is found, and if not, do a read operation, print the result and back again. After the last number read, `fgetc()` still returns not `EOF`, so the loop enters again and you read.... nothing, so `printf()` prints nothing intelligible. Now it is when you have reached `EOF`, and the next time you ask it, `fgetc()` returns `EOF`.

Try changing your code as follows. I use `feof()` instead of `fgetc()` so I don't do an extra read to see if I have reached `EOF`.

```
FILE* fichier=NULL;
int i=0;
int ID[50];
int num; /* temporary storage for number read from file */

fichier = fopen("resultat.txt","r");
fscanf(fichier,"%d",&num); /* first read, outside read loop */
while(!feof(fichier) && i<50) /* now you can ask for EOF */
{
    ID[i] = num;     /* if not EOF, store data read */
    printf("%d\n",ID[i]); /* and print it */
    fscanf(fichier,"%d",&num); /* then, read some more */
    i++;
}
fclose(fichier);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should stop printing when `fscanf()` fails to read one data.

Also return value of `fopen()` should be checked in order to avoid passing `NULL` to file manipulating functions and invoking *undefined behavior*.

```
FILE* fichier=NULL;
fichier = fopen("resultat.txt","r");
int i=0;
int ID[50];
if (fichier != NULL) {
    while(i<50 && fscanf(fichier,"%d",&ID[i]) == 1){
        printf("%d\n",ID[i]);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fichier);
}
```